# When is ViewModel available in MvxPhonePage

Tags: mvvmcross

I need to ensure that the visible item of a list is the last. I was thinking about using ScrollTo from the LongListSelector (`MessagesList.ScrollTo(VM.Messages.Last())`) in the constructor of my view but the ViewModel property is not yet set. Is there another place( event) in the view cycle i can use to ensure that the item viewed is the last one ?

Comment: I have subscribed to Loaded event and it works . Is is the place to make this kind oF change ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ViewModel at any time in your code behind.

Inside MvvmCross, if you haven't already created one, then the framework itself will try to create one when `MvxPhonePage.OnNavigatedTo` is fired https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Views/MvxPhonePage.cs#L43